# KIVY loop through images on external condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, dictionary, kivy

I am trying to make a children's learning app using KIVY and gTTS where a child will be shown a random image and will have to identify it by saying what it is ("square" for square, "three" for 3 etc).

So far I have the menus working fine.
I am using `random.choice()` in a dictionary where the value is the image path and the key is "the name"

If I open the relevant screen the image is correctly selected at random and displayed using `def on_pre_enter(self, *args):` and gTTS kicks in fine as well using `def on_enter(self, *args):` **but only ONCE**

I want it to load a new random image once the user replies to the previous one for an X amount of loops but no matter what I try I cannot get it to work (I thought of putting everything on a  `for x in range()` loop as well as using a counter on a `while X < Y:` but without any success).

here's my .py file

```
import random
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import StringProperty


class MenuWindow(Screen):
    pass

class ShapeGame(Screen):
    rand_shape = StringProperty()
    def on_pre_enter(self, *args):        
        random_shape = {"square":'shapes/square.png', "triangle":'shapes/triangle.jpg', "circle":'shapes/circle.jpg'}
        random_shape_key, random_shape_value = random.choice(list(random_shape.items()))
        print(random_shape_key)
        self.rand_shape_key = random_shape_key
        self.rand_shape = random_shape_value
        
    def on_enter(self, *args):
        print(self.random_shape_key)

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MainApp(App):  
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file('Main.kv')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

and my .kv file

```
#:kivy 2.0
WindowManager:
    MenuWindow:
    ShapeGame:

<MenuWindow>:
    name: "menu"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height

        Label:
            id:"menu"
            text: "Menu Screen"
            font_size: 34
            
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint: 1.0, 0.2
            Button:
                text: "Shape Game"
                font_size: 22
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "shapes"
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
                
        Button:
            text: "Exit"
            font_size: 22
            size_hint: 1.0, 0.2
            on_release: app.root.current = exit() 

<ShapeGame>:
    name: "shapes"
    id: ShapeGame
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height
        Image:
            id:"shapes"
            screen: ShapeGame
            source: self.screen.rand_shape
            before_source: self.source

        BoxLayout:
            size_hint: 1.0, 0.2
            size: root.width, root.height
            Button:
                text: "Menu"
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "menu"
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
            Button:
                text: "Exit"
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = exit()
```

and [the entire repo](https://github.com/Giorgos-vr/Tina)

Comment: As there are multiple dependencies in your code someone may get demotivated to approach it. Try to make it as minimal (and ofcourse runnable) as possible by removing unrelated dependencies (that you think, not required to recreate the problem).

Comment: good point, I removed the gTTS stuff, as mentioned originally it is not the issue, this bit works fine. The question is how can I run the selection function on a loop and load a new image, this is where I'm failing

Comment: You need to re-edit your code to make it a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as there are more `Screen`s in `.kv` than in `.py` file.

Comment: Not sure how I can make it any simpler, I removed all the unnecessary bits, this is the block that's bothering me and it should work on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I can follow your problem, assuming that you want to shuffle images on entering screen after some time until some value reaches its limit.

For that you can use `Clock.schedule_interval` with some waiting time, say 2.0 sec.

Thus your `ShapeGame` will now look like,

```py
class ShapeGame(Screen):
    rand_shape = StringProperty()
    count = 0

    def on_pre_enter(self, *args):
        self.count = 0
        self.change_event = Clock.schedule_interval(self.chage_photo, 2.0)
        
    def chage_photo(self, *args):
        if self.count < 3:
            self.count += 1
        else:
            self.change_event.cancel()
        random_shape = {"square":'shapes/square.png', "triangle":'shapes/triangle.jpg', "circle":'shapes/circle.jpg'}
        random_shape_key, random_shape_value = random.choice(list(random_shape.items()))
        print(random_shape_key)
        self.rand_shape_key = random_shape_key
        self.rand_shape = random_shape_value
```

You should change `source: self.screen.rand_shape` to `source: root.rand_shape`.

You may also trigger the same action by a button instead of using `Clock.schedule`.

Comment: Thank you, I eventually found it on my own in the documentation. I was looking at the "screen manager" section when I sould be looking at ["Events and properties"](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/events.html)).

I'll accept your answer but in case someone sees this in the future I want to add this too from the documentation.

"Events are an important part of Kivy programming. That may not be surprising to those with GUI development experience, but it’s an important concept for newcomers. Once you understand how events work and how to bind to them, you will see them everywhere in Kivy."